# Why is my array variable not working in setState, but when I declare my variable explicitly it works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a react application that requires a lot of data manipulation and trying setState with certain data when a button is clicked, so that is the only data that is rendered. Everything runs fine with no errors, however the state is not changed. When I hardcode the data in the array variable, it does change the state to what I hardcoded. This function is added to a button 'Clicks'. The functionality of the button works when I try a simple alert message in the createClicks function.

I've tried changing the scope of the variable, but that doesn't seem to help. I think it might have something to do with the inner function that manipulates the data is not running.

```
createClicks = () => {
    const clicksArr = [];
    const groupByProperties = ['date_start'];
    const groupResult = groupBy({ Group: this.state.data, By: groupByProperties });
    for (let i = 0; i < groupResult.length; i++) {
    let clicks = groupResult[i].reduce((acc, curr) => acc + parseFloat(curr.clicks), 0);
    clicksArr.push(clicks);
    };
    this.setState({
      series: [
        {
          name: "Clicks",
          data: clicksArr,
        },
      ]
    })

  };
```

The for loop and reduce function spits out [17894, 18159, 16696, 14089, 12919, 12457, 14783], but that does not go to state when I set 'data: clicksArr'. If I hardcode the 'const clicksArr = [17894, 18159, 16696, 14089, 12919, 12457, 14783]', it works.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you need and what your `groupResult` data looks like ? In this line `this.setState({series: [...]})`, why `series` should be an array, you will push data to it by some other way or at somewhere else in your code? Can you show the error log on the browser :D

Comment: Data is an array of objects so after I run groupBy on it, it separates the data into an array of arrays of objects, separated by date so I can plug it into a charts x values. I can then run the reduce function on that to find out the individual data points for each date. There is no error log on the browser. The react developer tools just shows the state is not updated, but when I hardcode it above it works perfectly.